# Detect scanner input in java (double or int)

Tags: java, integer, double, java.util.scanner, detect

I was trying to do this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prov{
    public static void main(){
        Scanner getInfo = new Scanner(System.in);
        showInfo(getInfo.next());

    }
    public void showInfo(int numb){
        System.out.println("You typed this integer: " + numb);
    }
        public void showInfo(double numb){
        System.out.println("You typed this double: " + numb);
    }
}
```

but it doesnt work no matter if I look for scanner.next or scanner.nextInt it wont just get a double when i write a double and an int when I type an int.

Thank You !

Comment: That's because `next` returns a string. Which is neither of those options.

Comment: getInfo.next(); returns a String... This code doesn't even compile...

Comment: I know that it returns a string but i'm asking how can I do it to work. I also forgotten to add String[] args in the public static void main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next() method returns a String not a number, specifically not even an int or double, to fix this, you need to test if the next is a int or is a double. Ie:

```
if (getInfo.hasNextInt()) {
    showInfo(getInfo.nextInt());
}else if(getInfo.hasNextDouble()) {
    showInfo(getInfo.nextDouble());
}else{
    //Neither int or double
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @user2896551 Its fixed now, I forgot you need to check for int first than double

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = scanner.nextInt();

} else if(scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    double d = scanner.nextDouble();

} else {
     scanner.next(); // discard the word
```

I suggest you read the Javadoc for all the other options it has.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment because I am lacking rep, but I think Peter answer needs a little correction, namely we need to change the order of IFs, to make int check first: if(scanner.hasNextInt()) { int i = scanner.nextInt(); } else if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) { double d = scanner.nextDouble(); In Peter code, when double is checked first, when we input integer - e.g. "6" - it will count is as double "6.0". If we check for integer first this problem does not occur.

Comment: @Jakras Good point, though this makes reading the `int` redundant,as any `int` can be read as a `double` without loss of precision.