# How to parse user input into corresponding type

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I need to write a Java program that takes two inputs from the user and calculates the sum. That part is simple but the user is allowed to enter any type - int or double. I have to figure out how to convert the input into the *type* of number the user entered. If they enter a number with a decimal, it has to be put into a double variable. If it's a plain number, it HAS to be an int. And, we can't ask the user what they're going to use. If they enter a non-numerical input, we can't throw an exception. How should my program work if the user enters 7 and 12.4?

I'm new to Java and have been studying the scanner class but can't figure this out. I understand how to do it for one type only; that's pretty simple. Please help!

Comment: Check out the `hasInt()` and `hasDouble()` methods.

Comment: Explain in more detail why it "has to be an int."  `double` can be used perfectly well even to store integer values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect scanner input in java (double or int)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470591/detect-scanner-input-in-java-double-or-int)

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I'll look into those methods now.  Also, it has to be an int because for example if you enter a 4 and 5 but they are stored in double variables the sum will output 9.0 - and having that .0 there isn't "smart" programming according to my professor, the sum should be a clean and simple 9 by itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a = 0;
double b = 0.0;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
   a = sc.nextInt();
} else if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
   b = sc.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to check in the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

if (scn.hasNextDouble()){    
    double dblVal= scn.nextDouble();
}
else if (scn.hasNextInt()){
    int intVal= scn.nextInt();
}
```

You can check using `hasNextInt()` or `hasNextDouble()` as above